# How to set CKEditor5 textarea cannot be empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor5 now

And the textarea is:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" rows="10" cols="30" id="editor"></textarea>
```

I want to set this field that cannot be empty so tried I 'required' attribute, but it makes the form cannot be sent out (to database).

Then I tried to stop my form sending content to the database if it is empty: (PHP)

```
if(!empty($post_content))
{
   ...create query and send query to  database...
}
else
{
   do nothing
}
```

However, I still able to send an empty content to the database.

Because it will send some html tag to the database even though I submit an empty content.

In the database, I can see there are html tags stored in the column cell like

```
<p></p>
```

It depended on the font-style when using CKEditor for input. It also can be `<i></i>`

Are there other approaches which can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue, came up with this:

```
if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i", strip_tags($post_content))){

}
```

worked on all my testing. strip tags alone would fail if some one pressed enter a few times then submitted. This only checks if you have at least one a-z you may want to be more rigorist and have a minimum, or allow for only numbers, but we dont know exactly what you expect here so its a best guess.

Comment: for your solution, how about: 
if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]\d/i", strip_tags($post_content))){} to check both of uppercase and lowercase, also number 0-9 ?

Comment: you tell me, its your question. but /i is case insensitive, so need for a-zA-Z and /i just pick one

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#editor").val()) {
    // textarea is not empty
   //...create query and send query to  database...
}
else{
 //do nothing
}
```

You can also use $.trim to remove white-space:

```
if ($.trim($("#editor").val())) {
    // textarea is not empty or not contains  white-space
    //...create query and send query to  database...
}
else{
   //do nothing
}
```

Comment: ignores the problem with html only being returned